# Proper SELECT Query When Expecting Multiple Results

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to come up with the proper query for my problem.  Basically, I might have over 100 of the exact same result if I do:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM highway WHERE state  = 'VA'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    //code
```

With this I would get:

```
    95
    95
    95
    95 (and on and on...)
    64
    64
    64 (and on and on...)
```

What would be the proper query to just get:

```
    95
    64
    66
    81
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `DESCRIBE highway;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) keyword:

> The `ALL` and `DISTINCT` options specify whether duplicate rows should be
>   returned. `ALL` (the default) specifies that all matching rows should be
>   returned, including duplicates. `DISTINCT` specifies removal of
>   duplicate rows from the result set. It is an error to specify both
>   options. `DISTINCTROW` is a synonym for `DISTINCT`.

So:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM highway WHERE state  = 'VA'
```

But if your resultset has duplicates when considering certain columns, it seems to me that your database tables are likely poorly designed. Have you considered further [normalising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) them?

Comment: The tables are set up as such:
state->highway->exit->features

Since there are multiple exits on each highway, it was the best way I could come up with to design it.

That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: @Go3Team: You definitely want to normalise that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY columname` in your query.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM highway WHERE state  = 'VA' GROUP BY columnameof9596etc.";
```